# Instructive sources for arguing without elements

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation

There is a trend in mathematics towards reasoning without elements if possible (coming from category theory, I presume). I see the appeal and want to learn how to argue avoiding the use of elements, but in our lectures this isn’t done. (At least not to the extent that I think is possible, and instead, more traditonal arguments are favored.)

I’m a bit of a lazy person, so I won’t work through formal introductions to category theory – although I have basic knowlegde of categories and I’m not reluctant to look up a particular concept or theory.

So I’m looking for good, *instructive* sources for learning arguing without elements, something focusing on problems and how to approach them – maybe even a documented collection of element-free proofs for common results. Are there any?

Comment: You could start by looking at the chapter on abelian categories in _Categories for the working mathematician_.

Comment: @k.stm: Sorry for not being modest, but one source is the vast collection of my math.SE posts which contain the word "universal property" or "Yoneda Lemma". ;-) That being said, I think that there is still no book on undergraduate level which explains element-free and categorical thinking consistently. I plan to write one next year, it's already started.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg You plan to write one? That’s great news! But how about graduate level books?